# Format my bootcamp partition to NTFS

Tags: mac, ntfs, boot-camp, format

Bootcamp is telling me that my bootcamp partition (that it created) is the wrong format. Does anyone know how to format bootcamp partitions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Bootcamp* is telling you, or the *Windows installation CD* is telling you?  If the latter, simply format the partition using the Windows installer's built-in utility (in other words, as part of the installation process).

You can format the partition from within OSX using the Disk Utility, but you can only format it to FAT, not NTFS.